# fabric samples first network byfn sh up Channel creation failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, channel

Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...
+ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
cat: log.txt: Permission denied
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed

Comment: you are getting `permission denied` error when the command is trying to `cat logs.txt`. fix the file permission issue and it'll work. 

Also check the `owner` of `log.txt` and the directory in which log.txt is present using command `ls -lh`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting permission denied error. If you are using Ubuntu then type the following command to give full access permissions to the directory in which your fabric network is residing,

```
sudo chmod -R 777 'path to the first network directory'
```